# Unity хочу что бы по нажатию клавиши корабль например резко ускорялся или резко останавливался

Tags: unity3d

Хочу что бы по нажатию клавиши корабль например резко ускорялся или резко останавливался. Но он это категорически делать не хочет. Вот мой код:

```cs
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerControls : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float thrustSpeed; // скорость поворота
    public float turnSpeed;  // скорость движения
    public float stop = 1f;

    public float hoverPower; // сила зависать
    public float hoverHeight; // высота зависания

    //private float thrustInput;
    //private float turnInput;
 
    private Rigidbody myRigidbody;

    void Start()
    {
        myRigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();        
    }

    void Update()
    {
        // ввод с клавиатуры
        float thrustInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        float turnInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

        // Поворот корабля 
        myRigidbody.AddRelativeTorque(0f, turnInput * turnSpeed, 0f);

        // Перемещение корабля 
        myRigidbody.AddRelativeForce(0f, 0f, thrustInput * thrustSpeed);

        // Hovering  Зависание
        Ray ray = new Ray(transform.position, -transform.up);
        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, hoverHeight))
        {
            float proportionalHeight = (hoverHeight - hit.distance) / hoverHeight;
 
            //Debug.Log(proportionalHeight);
 
            Vector3 appliedHoverForce = Vector3.up * proportionalHeight * hoverPower;
            myRigidbody.AddForce(appliedHoverForce, ForceMode.Acceleration);
        }

        // скрипт огня
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
        {
            myRigidbody.AddRelativeForce(0f, 0f, thrustInput * stop);
            Debug.Log("Fire1 ON " + stop);
        }
 
        else if (Input.GetButtonUp("Fire1"))
        {
            myRigidbody.AddRelativeForce(0f, 0f, thrustInput * thrustSpeed);
            Debug.Log("Fire1 OFF" + stop);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Удостоверься, что у твоего объекта есть компонент `Rigidbody` и увеличь значения `thrustInput` и `turnInput` в инспекторе. Это минимально необходимые действия, чтобы твой код двигал объект.

[image: Инспектор]

Comment: Спасибо за совет!